# Flutter: how to groupby of personality

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I want groupBy of famousAs of this data.

I got my data from api something like this

```
Personality:[
  0: {
      "FullName":"Harry Potter",
      "DateOfBirth": "2020/02/16",
      "Department":"Branch Operation",
      "BirthDay":"Friday"
      "famousAs":"Actor"
   },
  1: {
      "FullName":"John Wick",
      "DateOfBirth": "2020/02/16",
      "Department":"Finance",
      "BirthDay":"Friday"
      "famousAs":"Actor"
   },
  2: {
      "FullName":"Priyanka Chopara",
      "DateOfBirth":2020/02/19,
      "Department":"Loan",
      "BirthDay":"Monday"
      "famousAs":"Actress"
   }
]
```

when i check ,type of this data then it is showing List of dynamic

Comment: *"I want groupBy of famousAs of this data."* - use [groupListsBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/groupListsBy.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your want to group list of data according to their property value.

You can use .where() method to filter out the list.

```
List filter(List items, String value) =>
    items.where((element) => element['famousAs'] == value).toList();
```

**First the api response data from your question is invalid.**

If your List is same as following above filter function will work fine.

or if your api response is HashMap change to Map first

```
[
  {
    "FullName": "Harry Potter",
    "DateOfBirth": "2020/02/16",
    "Department": "Branch Operation",
    "BirthDay": "Friday",
    "famousAs": "Actor"
  },
  {
    "FullName": "John Wick",
    "DateOfBirth": "2020/02/16",
    "Department": "Finance",
    "BirthDay": "Friday",
    "famousAs": "Actor"
  },
  {
    "FullName": "Priyanka Chopara",
    "DateOfBirth": 2020 / 02 / 19,
    "Department": "Loan",
    "BirthDay": "Monday",
    "famousAs": "Actress"
  }
]
```

Usage..

```
final actors = filter(items, 'Actor');
final actresses = filter(items, 'Actress');
```